# SQL IF condition if GROUP BY statement

Tags: sql

I have some question about IF condition in SQL
Is it possible to use the next syntax in SQL query? I`m interesting about if condition in group by statement

```
"SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE... IF(order_id !=0, GROUP BY order_id, GROUP BY other_field)"
```

Comment: Which DBMS? What's order_id, a column or a parameter? (According to ANSI SQL only column-names can be listed in the GROUP BY clause.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY case when order_id <> 0 
              then order_id
              else other_field
         end
```

Answer (score 4):

First, you shouldn't be doing `select *` with `group by`.  The query would (normally) be rejected with a syntax error in most databases.

Second, the SQL standard is `case`.

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
select (case when order_id != 0 then order_id end) as order_id,
       (case when order_id = 0 then other_field end) as other_field,
       count(*)
from table t
group by (case when order_id != 0 then order_id end),
         (case when order_id = 0 then other_field end);
```

Note that I split the logic into two `case` statements.  This just makes it easier if the types of the fields are not the same -- you don't have to deal with things like how to convert from one type to another.

Comment: This is absolutely the correct syntax, the answer marked as correct will effectively hide all the elements in the 'THEN' part of the statement. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE statement rather. Somthing like this-

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE... 
GROUP BY CASE WHEN order_id !=0 THEN order_id 
ELSE other_field END;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also achievable with [IIF()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_iif.asp) operator:

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM TABLE 
WHERE... 
GROUP BY IIF(order_id <> 0, order_id, other_field)
```